# Read a file and put specific values to an array

Tags: bash, shell, file-read

I am a newbie to bash scripting. I have a file containing some values. I want to put all the values of a specific key into an array in bash. The file looks like this.

```
file.properties
name=val1
name=val2
name=val3
age=val4
```

I want to read this file and get all the name values into one array in bash.

Comment: Just do it then, no one stopping you.. Here are some helpers: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Associative_Arrays Just set `IFS='='` and read the file line by line and for each line set the elements on an array.

Comment: Read each line, use *parameter expansion* to remove the `name=` portion and store the remainder in an array. `declare -a arr; while read -r line; do [ "${line%=*}" = "name" ] && arr+=("${line##*=}"); done < your_file.txt; declare -p arr`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    arr=("${arr[@]}" "$line")
done < <(grep name= file.properties | sed "s/name=//")
echo "${arr[@]}"
```